Upgrading to expo 52 causes an error message that node-fetch cannot import node:http because the React runtime doesn't include the Node standard lib
I am trying to upgrade my expo project to version 52. After some issues with npm 10.9.0 not working I got a fresh node-modules directory installed.
But trying to run the program in expo-go I get the message

The package at "node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "node:http".It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library.

Weird because when I check what modules use that dependency there are many from the standard React native and Expo libraries.
I suspect that something is causing it to use the Node-fetch instead of react-fetch. But I haven't been able to figure it out
I have tried it in both the old architecture and the new architecture.
